How to convert from py torch to tflite
I have been working with yolov8s model and have generated best.pt model from google colab but I have problems now in google colab, So,I want to convert the pt model to tensorflow lite on vscode.
Any ideas?

If you are using the ultralytics library you can use their export() function.
model.export(format='tflite')

Here is a link to its documentation: https://docs.ultralytics.com/modes/export/#__tabbed_1_1

While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - From Review
